# ValueError: dimension mismatch tfidf naive bayes

Tags: python

I really need your help. I am working on text classification, I used `tfidf` and `naive bayes ngram` so I saved my  model then I loaded it to reuse and classify a phrase, the problem is after I used the `tfidf` loaded and when I tried to use my model I got this error

> "ValueError: dimension mismatch"
>   Thanks in advance

```
from Feature_Engineering import clean_text_test
import pandas as pd 
X_raw = 'Spécialisées dans l’achat et la revente de produits de luxes, ces organisations parviennent à blanchir des centaines de millions d’euros par an. Le luxe à la française fascine les jeunes Chinois de la classe moyenne. C’est tellement vrai qu’en région parisienne des organisations occultes profitent de la revente de vêtements et d’articles de maroquinerie pour blanchir de l’argent provenant de fraudes fiscales, du proxénétisme ou du trafic de drogue. Les enquêteurs du deuxième district de police judiciaire de Paris viennent de mettre à bas, à l’automne dernier, un réseau fort d’au moins six hommes et femmes d’origine chinoise, âgés de 30 et 40 ans, qui entre 2017 et 2018, a fait circuler plus de cinq millions d’euros entre la France et la Chine, sans payer un centime de taxe.'

X_final=clean_text_test(X_raw)

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'X': [X_final]})

tf1 = pickle.load(open("tf_ngram.pkl", 'rb'))

# Create new tfidfVectorizer with old vocabulary
tf1_new = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(5,5),  lowercase = True,
                          max_features = 50000, vocabulary = tf1.vocabulary_)
X_tf1 = tf1_new.fit_transform(df_train.X)

filename = 'Naive_Bayes_CountVect'

loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

ypredict=loaded_model.predict(X_tf1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you fit your TF-IDF vectorizer again ? You just need to do `X_tf1 = tf1.transform(df_train.X)`

Comment: I used X_tf1 = tf1.transform(df_train.X) but I still have the same error